# Can I use the lazy-option of the Angular PrimeNG treeTable without virtual scroll?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, primeng, virtualscroll, primeng-treetable

Hey guys i stumbled about some problems with the lazy loading option of the prime ng treeTable. I need to use the lazyLoad event (Output property "onLazyLoad") without the virtual scroller behavior. Is this somehow supported by the treeTable component?

Something like this:

```
<p-treeTable [value]="virtualFiles" [columns]="cols" [scrollable]="true" [rows]="20" 
    [virtualRowHeight]="34" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadNodes($event)"
    [totalRecords]="totalRecords" scrollHeight="400px">
</p-treeTable>
```

If it's not possible to use lazy loading without the virtual scroller it would be okay if I at least could prevent it from destroying the previous loaded Elements.

I already tried setting the rows-property to the length of the values-array to prevent fetching more data when scrolling upwards.

Would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Do you mean using `(onLazyLoad)="loadNodes($event)"` without `[scrollable]="true"`?

Comment: @StepUp No I mean using it without [virtualScroll]="true"

Answer (score 2):

In my view, virtual scrolling is an alternative to paging.

How does it work?

From my point of view, the virtual scrolling relies on calculations that are based on the `[virtualRowHeight]="34"` and `[rows]="20"`, and then it calculates the desired size  of data to be loaded. So, it is necessary to predefine `[virtualRowHeight]`  and `[rows]`, to ensure the proper functioning of the data virtualization, loading, and rendering of the correct items.

So when you work with many rows, it is necessary to use `[virtualScroll]="true"`

Comment: The problem is I can't use a paginator

Comment: I get your point, that it is necessary if you're working with big datasets. But in my situation we are just talking about maybe 300 - 600 records. Basically virtual scrolling is just not the right approach in my situation due to other features I've implemented, which require jumping to specific positions in the list.

Comment: @SimonLüscher so if you don't have any performance issues, then it is possible to use without `[virtualScroll]="true"`.